# flutter youtube video inside container or box

Tags: youtube, dart, flutter, containers

I follow the example of Flutter [flutter_youtube 1.1.1](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_youtube#-readme-tab-) , but it only can click the button and start a page with youtube video. May I know how to put the youtube video in a container or box?

```
 void playYoutubeVideoEdit() {
    var youtube = new FlutterYoutube();

    youtube.onVideoEnded.listen((onData) {
      //perform your action when video playing is done
    });

    FlutterYoutube.playYoutubeVideoByUrl(
      apiKey: "fdsfsgfdsgf-Fp_KPafdsfdgfdgfdssdfsWVHCoiWCVwh8",
      videoUrl: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5jK8W4wlu8",
      autoPlay: true,
      fullScreen: false
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

also you wrote the right answer ;)
[example here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_youtube#-example-tab-)
if you want see thumbnail, you must use [youtube data api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets)

Comment: it only can click the button and start a page with youtube video. It can't not put the youtube video into a container and play as the image above.

Comment: Its really strange that flutter is now on 0.96 version and it has no solution for youtube video even though flutter and youtube both are google's.